# How can I assert that a function produces an Ok result, otherwise panic?

Tags: rust, assert

When a function errors in a test, I use this pattern:

```
if let Err(err) = func() {
    panic!("got error on export: {:?}", err);
}
```

Is there a macro for asserting an `Ok` result and get the Err printed otherwise?

Comment: `func().expect("got error on export")`.

Comment: [Shortcuts for Panic on Error: `unwrap` and `expect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#shortcuts-for-panic-on-error-unwrap-and-expect)

Comment: If you need a dynamic panic message, `unwrap_or_else` is quite useful, e.g.: `let file = File::open(file_name).unwrap_or_else(|e| panic!("opening {}: {}", file_name, e));`